# ASP.NET MVC 3 Strongly-typed Views: Why do compiler errors disappear/are ignored when a view is not open in VS editor?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, strongly-typed-view

Every time we make changes to a model we need to open all views using that model in VS editor and see if there are any errors before proceeding with a new deployment. Is there a way to enforce compiler errors in a strongly-typed view and prevent a project build so that no embarrassing errors ever appear on runtime? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile cshtml and aspx files at build time instead of runtime. To do this unload project, open it for edit, find `<MvcBuildViews>` tag and change value to true.
If you have edmx files in your project clean solution before first edit.

Comment: Great! This is the key: <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews> (It makes builds a little too slow but i guess that's better than hidden bugs!)

Comment: Oh! Forgot to cover tag... Fixed. But anyway you found it :)